# Sway doesn't execute the script on startup

Tags: bash, arch-linux, wayland, sway

I have two bash scripts and I want them to run on startup. I'm using sway and I execute scripts with **exec** word like this

`exec /home/crawraps/.config/sway/gdrive-push-sync.sh`
`exec /home/crawraps/.config/sway/gdrive-pull-sync.sh`

The problem is that one of these scripts is working and the other is not. In particular `gdrive-push-sync.sh` is not working. Both of them are executable and both of them are working if I run them manually.

I've tested `push` script manually and also I can see `pull` script running in `htop` but no `push` script.

I'm using Arch-linux

*gdrive-push-sync.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $GDRIVE
ignore=".gd/"

inotifywait $GDRIVE -m -r -e modify -e create -e delete -e move |
  while read directory action file; do
    relPath=${directory#"$GDRIVE"}
    if [ "$relPath" != "$ignore" ]; then
      echo "$action $relPath$file"
      drive push $relPath$file
    fi
  done
```

*gdrive-pull-sync.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $GDRIVE

while true
do
drive pull
sleep 10m
done
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would seem that your scripts are relying on an environment variable `$GDRIVE`. Can you edit your post to explain when and where this variable is set and exported?